# Database to XML (and vice versa) through Java

Tags: java, xml, database, jdbc, jaxb

I'm trying to find some tutorial examples on how to exchange data between databases and XML files using Java, from getting and setting specific data from a database to (if possible) change how the database is structured.

I have conducted research into this, but I'm unsure on whether its JDBC I should look into, XML:DB, JAXB, or if any of them are even relevant to what I'm trying to do.

I plan to create a database example, and then see if I can exchange data to and from an XML file using Java, just to see how it works; what should I look into in order to accomplish this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After further research into my query, I found JDBC (database manipulations) and XStream (XML conversions) to be my most preferred solutions.

For JDBC, I referred to [this link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/index.htm)

For XStream, I referred to [this link](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html)

Thank you for your replies.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in many other ways but I do this way

1. Get data from Databases
2. Convert it to HashMap
3. Create a JaxB detail class matching your schema
4. Create a constructor in the JaxB class which accepts the HashMap and assign the data to the variables in JaxB
5. Convert JaxB object to XML/JSON by Marshaling
6. Write to a file if you want

If your new to Jax-B view this tutorial [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/)!

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

1. Use a JPA implementation (EclipseLink, Hibernate, Open JPA, etc) to convert the database data to/from Java objects.
2. Use a JAXB implementation (EclipseLink MOXy, reference implementation, etc) to convert the Java objects to/from XML.

Comment: Yeah I talked to someone with a very similar process; something about reading data from a database and converting it into a POJO using JDBC, to then convert it into an XML using XStream.

Comment: @KurtissBolam - JPA implementations handle the database to object part for you.  You wouldn't have to deal directly with JDBC:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-25.html